# Render elements in order by array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, jsx

```
const Chat = () => {
  const [array1, setArray1] = useState(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']);
  const [array2, setArray2] = useState(['four', 'two']);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {array1.map((d) => {
          return array2.forEach((e) => {
            return d === e ? <li>{e}</li> : '';
          });
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

I expect my list items to render in order:

-"two"

-"four"

My logic, I will go through array1 and if I find matches from array2, then output them to the renderer.
However, nothing comes to the render at all. Tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: ForEach will not return anything use map instead.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your for each method does not return anything, so you're really just returning an array of undefined. You can keep the same logic, even though it's a bit odd to set something in state that you won't mutate:

```
const Chat = () => {
  const [array1, setArray1] = useState(["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]);
  const [array2, setArray2] = useState(["four", "two"]);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {array1.flatMap((d) => {
          return array2.map((e) => {
            return d === e ? <li>{e}</li> : "";
          });
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

Since you're returning an array of arrays technically, and flat map does the same logic and flattens the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
const Chat = () => {
  const [array1, setArray1] = useState(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'])
  const [array2, setArray2] = useState(['four', 'two'])
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {array1
          .filter((e) => array2.includes(e))
          .map((e) => (
            <li>{e}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Chat
```